# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails'

Tags: python

```
def fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails(self, orders):
 fyers = self.brokerHandle
 orderBook = None
 try:
  orderBook = fyers.orderbook()
 except Exception as e:
  logging.error('%s Failed to fetch order book', self.broker)
  return
 logging.info('%s Order book length = %d', self.broker, len(orderBook))
 numOrdersUpdated = 0
 for bOrder in orderBook:
  foundOrder = None
  for order in orders:
   if order.orderId == bOrder['orderBook']['id']:
    foundOrder = order
    break
  
   if foundOrder != None:
```

---

```
   def fetchAndUpdateAllTradeOrders():
     allOrders = []
     for trade in TradeManager.trades:
      if trade.entryOrder != None:
        allOrders.append(trade.entryOrder)
      if trade.slOrder != None:
        allOrders.append(trade.slOrder)
      if trade.targetOrder != None:
        allOrders.append(trade.targetOrder)

    TradeManager.getOrderManager().fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails(orders = allOrders)
```

---

It returns the error:
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\AlgoTraderFyers\src\trademgmt\TradeManager.py", line 76, in run
TradeManager.fetchAndUpdateAllTradeOrders()
File "d:\AlgoTraderFyers\src\trademgmt\TradeManager.py", line 227, in fetchAndUpdateAllTradeOrders
TradeManager.getOrderManager().fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails(orders = allOrders)*
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails'**

It was working with the other broker(zerodha). Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails'

This means that the thing you are calling the `fetchAndUpdateAllOrderDetails()` function on is "None".

So in this case, the return value of `TradeManager.getOrderManager()` is None.

Are you returning anything from the `getOrderManager()` function?

Comment: Hey! getOrderManager() returns orderManager. Thanks for bringing it to my notice. The problem was i used "Fyers" instead of "fyers".